# Can this SQL Query be optimized to run faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization

I have an SQL Query (For SQL Server 2008 R2) that takes a very long time to complete. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it?

```
SELECT @count = COUNT(Name)
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.Name = @name AND t.Code NOT IN (SELECT Code FROM ExcludedCodes)
```

Table1 has around 90Million rows in it and is indexed by Name and Code.
ExcludedCodes only has around 30 rows in it.

This query is in a stored procedure and gets called around 40k times, the total time it takes the procedure to finish is 27 minutes.. I believe this is my biggest bottleneck because of the massive amount of rows it queries against and the number of times it does it.

So if you know of a good way to optimize this it would be greatly appreciated! If it cannot be optimized then I guess im stuck with 27 min...

**EDIT**

I changed the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS` and it cut the time down to 10:59, so that alone is a massive gain on my part. I am still going to attempt to do the group by statement as suggested below but that will require a complete rewrite of the stored procedure and might take some time... (as I said before, im not the best at SQL but it is starting to grow on me. ^^)

Comment: man, you're doing a parsed count of 90M-30 rows 40000 times... what do you expect exactly :D

Comment: Heve you considered using JOINs?

Comment: lol i didn't expect it to be fast, but im not an SQL quru so I wasn't for sure if i was missing something very simple. And no, name is not unique unfortunatly.. :(

Comment: No I haven't really thought of using a join in this situation, wasn't really sure if it would be faster/necessary honestly.. But like i said, I'm no guru! lol

Comment: is there an INDEX on ExcludedCodes ?

Comment: @whytheq no there isn't, but I didn't think it was necessary since it was such a small table? (sorry I didn't see your comment earlier)

Comment: Index probably won't help, since it will have to do a scan and it is probably all on a single page anyway. Unless there are a bunch of columns in the ExcludedCodes table that the OP hasn't told us about.

Comment: @mouters It is looping through all the entries in a seperate table and using the name from that table to do this query.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nope, only 2 columns, Code and CodeName ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to workarounds to get the query itself to respond faster, have you considered maintaining a column in the table that tells whether it is in this set or not? It requires a lot of maintenance but if the `ExcludedCodes` table does not change often, it might be better to do that maintenance. For example you could add a BIT column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD IsExcluded BIT;
```

Make it NOT NULL and default to 0. Then you could create a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX n ON dbo.Table1(name)
  WHERE IsExcluded = 0;
```

Now you just have to update the table once:

```
UPDATE t
  SET IsExcluded = 1
  FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExcludedCodes AS x
  ON t.Code = x.Code;
```

And ongoing you'd have to maintain this with triggers on both tables. With this in place, your query becomes:

```
SELECT @Count = COUNT(Name)
  FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE IsExcluded = 0;
```

**EDIT**

As for "NOT IN being slower than LEFT JOIN" here is a simple test I performed on only a few thousand rows:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I'm not sure why this query wouldn't do what you're after, and be far more efficient than your 40K loop:

```
SELECT src.Name, COUNT(src.*)
  FROM dbo.Table1 AS src
  INNER JOIN #temptable AS t
  ON src.Name = t.Name
  WHERE src.Code NOT IN (SELECT Code FROM dbo.ExcludedCodes)
  GROUP BY src.Name;
```

Or the LEFT JOIN equivalent:

```
SELECT src.Name, COUNT(src.*)
  FROM dbo.Table1 AS src
  INNER JOIN #temptable AS t
  ON src.Name = t.Name
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExcludedCodes AS x
  ON src.Code = x.Code
  WHERE x.Code IS NULL
  GROUP BY src.Name;
```

I would put money on either of those queries taking less than 27 minutes. I would even suggest that running *both* queries sequentially will be far faster than your one query that takes 27 minutes.

Finally, you might consider an indexed view. I don't know your table structure and whether your violate any of the restrictions but it is worth investigating IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for that test, I was actually wondering that myself a few days ago but went with the "NOT IN" option instead. Good choice I guess. ^^ And as for the adding of the IsExcluded bit, I cannot alter the table I am working with unfortunatly.. I had thought of doing something similar but it is not an option to alter it. ><

Comment: What exactly is #tempTable? I was looking through your answer and other answers and even my own question and I can't seem to place my finger on what exactly is in that table..

Comment: @BrandonStout you said: "its in a very crappy while loop I made that loops through a temp table one row at a time" - is that not a temp table? Does it not store the name you need to join on? If you show your actual code instead of just a portion, suggestions might be more accurate.

Comment: OH! sorry I forgot that I said that. and yes, I can see this working that way now.. I should be able to implement this fairly quickly, but as I am about to leave I will have to try it in the morning. I will let you know first thing tomorrow after it runs how much it helped. Thank you for your answer's btw, they have helped alot even though I was unable to use the IsExcluded bit. It gave me an idea for another problem I was having.

Comment: Ok, it ended up being more of a pain than I thought to add in that little bit of code.. lol but after i got it implemented and used it to remove another loop I had, it is now down to 1:33 Minutes! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You say this gets called around 40K times. WHy? Is it in a cursor? If so do you really need a cursor. Couldn't you put the values you want for @name in a temp table and index it and then join to it?

```
select t.name, count(t.name) 
from table t
join #name n on t.name = n.name 
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT Code FROM ExcludedCodes WHERE Code = t.code)
group by t.name
```

That might get you all your results in one query and is almost certainly faster than 40K separate queries. Of course if you need the count of all the names, it's even simpleer

```
select t.name, count(t.name) 
    from table t
NOT EXISTS (SELECT Code FROM ExcludedCodes WHERE Code = t
group by t.name
```

Comment: No its not in a cursor.. its in a very crappy while loop I made that loops through a temp table one row at a time.. I am interested in this method although i couldn't figure out how to get the group by to work correctly.. I'm going to look into this one a bit thanks!

Comment: While loops also run row by agonizing row.

Comment: @BrandonStout A while loop *is* a cursor. Why do you think it's any different? Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx ... Surely there is a set-based solution that doesn't require 40,000 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

`NOT EXISTS` typically performs better than `NOT IN`, but you should test it on your system.

```
SELECT @count = COUNT(Name)
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.Name = @name AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ExcludedCodes e WHERE e.Code = t.Code)
```

Without knowing more about your query it's tough to supply concrete optimization suggestions (i.e. code suitable for copy/paste). Does it really need to run 40,000 times? Sounds like your stored procedure needs reworking, if that's feasible. You could exec the above once at the start of the proc and insert the results in a temp table, which can keep the indexes from `Table1`, and then join on that instead of running this query.

This particular bit might not even be the bottleneck that makes your query run 27 minutes. For example, are you using a cursor over those 90 million rows, or scalar valued UDFs in your `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: I will attempt this and let you know! (might be awhile.. lol)

Comment: A lot of action on this question while I was editing. I see in the comments on HLGEM's answer that you're using a while loop. Work on getting rid of that, you'll almost certainly get a larger performance increase from optimizing out that loop than from changing `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: not need to return `e.code` might be slightly quicker still then. All that is required is `1`. I'll edit; feel free to delete.

Comment: O.o simply changing it from NOT IN to NOT EXISTS cut off 16 min.. dang.. ok, now to attempt the group by.

Comment: `@whytheq - That's quite the micro-optimization, and I'm skeptical about its potential effectiveness, but sure. I'd just pasted in code from the question and made minor changes for clarity. @Brandon Stout - Good to hear. I still recommend removing the loop if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about doing the query once and populating the data in a table variable or temp table?  Something like

```
insert into #temp (name, Namecount)
values Name, Count(name)
from table1 
where name not in(select code from excludedcodes)
group by name
```

And don't forget that you could possibly use a filtered index as long as the excluded codes table is somewhat static.

Comment: +1. I was just about to post something like this. I think that while the OP _could_ try to optimize the query, it's much more of a problem that it's being run 40k times.

Answer (score 0):

Start evaluating the execution plan. Which is the heaviest part to compute?
Regarding the relation between the two tables, use a JOIN on indexed columns: indexes will optimize query execution.